# How to render_template() with >=2 blocks in separate files?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Since `Jinja2` has blocks to break up templates into separate files using `{% block _name_ %}{% endblock %}` I imagine it should be fairly easy to implement that on `Flask`, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

### The pledge

I have this structure:

```
daddy_template.html
    son.html
    daughter.html
```

All templates have roughly the following content:

```
<!-- daddy_template.html -->
<div id="son">{% block son %}{% endblock %}</div>
<div id="daughter">{% block daughter %}{% endblock %}</div>

<!-- son.html -->
{% extends "daddy_template.html" %}
{% block son %}
<p>Knock, knock</p>
{% endblock %}

<!-- daughter.html -->
{% extends "daddy_template.html" %}
{% block daughter %}
<p>Who is it?</p>
{% endblock %}
```

### The turn

I am aware only of `render_template()` in Flask to prepare a template and it takes exactly one template at a time, so this omits all but the one block provided in the function parameter.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def daddy():
    return render_template('son.html')
```

### The prestige

So how do you have your cake and eat it to? In this case, have both `son.html` and `daughter.html` included into `daddy_template.html` at render time?

Comment: Blocks are not so you can create separate files, but so you can override the extended template in a child template.  You likely want to include them instead.

Comment: Thanks @sberry I should have asked earlier... I wouldn't have as many scratch marks on my forehead :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [include statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) instead of using blocks.

Comment: What about Python logic? Does include borrow all variables declared in `render_template()` and provides it to both the template in the parameter as well as all imports?

Comment: Pretty sure that question is answered in the docs I just linked to!

Comment: You're absolute right @djc, still it would've been nice if that was in the answer. Still, problem solved.